# the dart-define argument is not working for build

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using

```sh
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./build/info-apk --split-per-abi --dart-define=SOME_VAR=true
```

and

```dart
final someVar = String.fromEnvironment('SOME_VAR', defaultValue: 'false').toLowerCase() == 'true'
```

but `someVar` is false in the apk, what is wrong?

My flutter version: 2.2.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define `someVar` as `static const`

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @WebMaster for what concern the `const`, there is an open issue on github that talk about it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55870).
i put it as`static`because it's declared inside a static class.

Answer (score 0):

get it like this.

```
const some = String.fromEnvironment('SOME_VAR');

void main(List<String>? args) {
...
print(some);

or

print(const String.fromEnvironment('SOME_VAR'));
}
```